# How to mock/replace a class with a list

Tags: python, mocking, generator, python-unittest, python-mock

Basically I'm trying to do this:

```
class SeaLion(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def next(self):
        ...

def train():
    sea_lion = SeaLion(...)
    for tooth in sea_lion:
        .. do something
```

Then in my test file I have:

```
class TestTrain(TestCase):
    @patch('module.SeaLion')
    def test_train(self, mock_SeaLion):
        mock_SeaLion.return_value = [1,2,3]
        ...
```

Basically I want sea_lion in the train function to be a list instead of an instance of that class.

With the above code sea_lion is MagicMock(name='SeaLion()')

Comment: `mock_SeaLion = MagicMock()` - you need to go read about [what assignment means in Python](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), because assigning a new value to your `mock_SeaLion` local variable is obviously wrong.

Comment: Good point.  I took that line out.  Same issue as before though.

Comment: Your solution should work. Can you clarify your question if not?

Comment: Don't know if you are still having problems. But your code should be working. Is this your exact code?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import unittest
from mock import patch

class SeaLion(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        pass

def train():
    sea_lion = SeaLion()
    print(repr(sea_lion))
    for tooth in sea_lion:
        return True

    return False

class TestTrain(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('__main__.SeaLion')
    def test_train(self, mock_SeaLion):
        mock_SeaLion.return_value = [1]
        self.assertTrue(train())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Result:

```
[1]
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.044s

OK
```

Comment: Thanks.  That seems to be the same thing I was doing.    I guess there must be something wrong in my code somewhere.

Comment: The only difference is: @patch('__ main__.SeaLion').